# Terraform modules from another repository using a git branch as a source in a Azure DevOps pipeline with System Access token

Tags: azure, azure-devops, terraform, terraform-modules

I have a Terraform `main.tf` file that calls modules from another git repository.

```
module "ModuleName" {
  source = "git::https://OrgName@dev.azure.com/OrgName/SW/_git/AnotherRepoName?ref=BranchName"
```

My Azure DevOps Pipeline Yaml code looks like below to run on `ubuntu-latest`.

```
trigger:
  - None

pool:
  vmImage: 'ubuntu-latest'
```

And the Task looks like below:

```
- task: PowerShell@2
           displayName: powershell-job
           inputs:
             workingDirectory: '$(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory)/BranchPolicies/Terraform'
             targetType: 'inline'
             script: |
               write-host '$(SYSTEM_ACCESSTOKEN)'
               pwd
               $env:SYSTEM_ACCESSTOKEN = "$(System.AccessToken)"
               write-host '$(system.accesstoken)'
               git config --global http.https://dev.azure.com/OrgName/Infra.extraheader "AUTHORIZATION: bearer $env:SYSTEM_ACCESSTOKEN"
               terraform init
               terraform plan
               
           env:
             SYSTEM_ACCESSTOKEN: $(system.accesstoken)
```

The Terraform plan is failing and throws an error like below:

```
│ Could not download module "ModuleName" (main.tf:58) source code from
│ "git::https://OrgName@dev.azure.com/OrgName/SW/_git/AnotherRepoName?ref=BranchName":
│ error downloading
│ 'https://OrgName@dev.azure.com/OrgName/SW/_git/AnotherRepoName?ref=BranchName':
│ /usr/bin/git exited with 1: error: pathspec 'master' did not match any
│ file(s) known to git
```

Note: For security reasons I changed the OrgName and BranchNames in the logs as well.

Why is this looking for the Master branch instead of the BranchName which I mentioned in the script in the module source?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed this issue by updating the script like below, the issue is with environment variable names, it is working only with `AZDO_PERSONAL_ACCESS_TOKEN` and `AZDO_ORG_SERVICE_URL` names.

```
  script: |
               $env:AZDO_PERSONAL_ACCESS_TOKEN
               $env:AZDO_ORG_SERVICE_URL="https://dev.azure.com/<Org_name>"
               git config --global http.https://<Org_name>@dev.azure.com.extraheader "AUTHORIZATION: bearer $env:AZDO_PERSONAL_ACCESS_TOKEN"

env:
    AZDO_PERSONAL_ACCESS_TOKEN: $(System.AccessToken)
```

Answer (score 1):

On **Organization Settings** (or **Project Settings**) > **Pipelines** > **Settings** page:

- If the option "**`Limit job authorization scope to current project`**" is enabled, the token **`System.AccessToken`** can only access the resources within the current project where the pipeline is running.
- If the option "**`Limit job authorization scope to current project`**" is disabled, the token **`System.AccessToken`** can access the resources across projects within current Azure DevOps organization where the pipeline is running.

More details, see "[**Job authorization scope**](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/process/access-tokens?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml#job-authorization-scope)".

[image]

---

However, if the module source git repository you want to access is in a different Azure DevOps organization, the token **`System.AccessToken`** will be not possible to access it.

Since the token cannot access the repository, the task will be not able to list the existing branches from the repository. Then it may try to search for '**`master`**' as the default branch of the repository.

In this situation, you need to provide a PAT (Personal Access Token) which can access that git repository.

Comment: I cross-checked these settings and those look the same as your screenshot, However, I am still facing the same issue. Thanks, Bright Ran, for your answer.

Comment: @AditYa, Is the module git repository in the same Azure DevOps organization (or even in the same project) with the pipeline?

Comment: Both the repositories are under the same organization and project.

Comment: @AditYa, Try to use a PAT of your account instead of the **`system.accesstoken`** to see whether it can work.

Comment: I was able to resolve the issue and provide a solution. Thank you for your input.